# Convert object to array while removing non-number field names

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to convert an object to an array if it has this structure, while all fields are ignored which have an non-number field?

```
var obj = {
    0: 'some',
    1: 'thing',
    2: 'to convert',
    ignore: 'this'
}
```

result should be:

```
result = ['some', 'thing', 'to convert'];
```

with the correct order of the elements.

Comment: Does it have a `length` property?

Comment: what is with negative keys, or fractions? or sparse array?

Comment: Note being numerical is not enough to be an array index. `""`, `"-0"`, `" 0"`, `"1.2"`, `"4294967295"`, `"Infinity"` are not array indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has a `length` property, you can use `Array.from`:

```js
console.log(Array.from({
  0: 'some',
  1: 'thing',
  2: 'to convert',
  length: 3,
  ignore: 'this'
}));
```

Otherwise, assuming the indices are not sparse, you can iterate manually. Start from 0 and increment until you reach the end.

```js
var obj = {
  0: 'some',
  1: 'thing',
  2: 'to convert',
  ignore: 'this'
}, array = [], i = -1;
while(++i in obj) array[i] = obj[i];
console.log(array);
```

In general, you would need to iterate all string properties and [check if they are array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163612/1529630):

```js
function isArrayIndex(str) {
  return (str >>> 0) + '' === str && str < 4294967295
}
var obj = {
  0: 'some',
  1: 'thing',
  2: 'to convert',
  ignore: 'this'
}, array = [];
for(var key of Object.keys(obj))
  if(isArrayIndex(key)) array[key] = obj[key];
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster but more complex way is :

```
var obj = {
  0: 'some',
  1: 'thing',
  2: 'to convert',
  ignore: 'this'
}, res = [], keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  if(!isNaN(+keys[i]))
    res.push(obj[keys[i]]);
```

Comment: `isNaN` is not the proper way to check array indices.

Comment: This function is here to check if the array is a number of not

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var obj = {
    0: 'some',
    1: 'thing',
    2: 'to convert',
    ignore: 'this'
};

var copy = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e=>{
  if(!isNaN(e)) copy[e] = obj[e];
});

console.log(Object.values(copy));
```

Comment: The downvoter (not me) might have thought that instead of copying all properties and deleting non-numeric ones, it would be better to copy only the desired ones.

Comment: @Oriol Thank you for the input! fixed now!

Comment: Your code has a little problem : it's not ES5-compatible, only ES6 which is not implemented in all browsers.