# Check if property name is array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I want to assign some properties to an array, but only if they are array indices. Otherwise some implementations might switch the underlying structure to a hash table and I don't want that.

For example, these are array indices: `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"`, `"4294967294"`

But these are not: `"abcd"`, `"0.1"`, `"-0"`, `"-1"`, `" 2"`, `"1e3"`, `"4294967295"`

Is there an easy way to test if a string is an array index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5, [Array indices](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) are defined as follows:

> A property name *P* (in the form of a String value) is an *array
>   index* if and only if [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)([ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(*P*)) is equal to
>   *P* and [ToUint32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.6)(*P*) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

(The [definition in ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type) is worded differently but should be equivalent.)

Then, the code would be

```
function isArrayIndex(str) {
  return (str >>> 0) + '' === str && str < 4294967295
}
```

Step by step,

- ToUint32(*P*) can be done by shifting 0 bits with the [unsigned right shift operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3)

  ```
  P >>> 0
  ```
- ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) can be done by concatenating the empty string with [the addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1).

  ```
  (P >>> 0) + ''
  ```
- ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) is equal to *P* can be checked with [the strict equals operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4).

  ```
  (P >>> 0) + '' === P
  ```

  Note this will also ensure that *P* really was in the form of a String value.
- ToUint32(*P*) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1 can be checked with the [strict does-not-equal operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.5)

  ```
  (P >>> 0) !== 4294967295
  ```

  But once we know ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) is equal to *P*, one of the following should be enough:

  ```
  P !== "4294967295"
  P < 4294967295
  ```