# javascript object keys order with negative value

Tags: javascript

I was under impression that ES6 has introduced new features to get object properties in creation order using methods like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, `Reflect.ownKeys` etc but while working on a problem I realised for negative keys the order is not maintained.

```js
const object1 = {
  "-1": 'somestring',
  "3": 42,
  "2": false,
  "-3": true
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1));
// expected output: Array ["-1", "3, "2", "-3"]
// actual output: ["2", "3", "-1", "-3"]

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
```

What would be the correct way to get keys in creation order for such scenario?

**EDIT: I dont want to sorted order, looking for creation order**

Comment: positive 32 bit integers are sorted by value and appears first.

Comment: only natural numbers are sorted in order

Comment: *"I dont want to sorted order, looking for creation order"* - mentioned this on an answer below but i'll re-iterate it here: **Because you have positive integer keys, it's not possible.** It's why objects should never be used for anything that's order-sensitive. Consider a `Map` instead.

Comment: From MDN page about [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames): _"The ordering of the non-enumerable properties in the array and the ordering among the enumerable properties is not defined."_

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ordering of keys does distinguish between array indices ([basically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163612/1048572) non-negative integers) and others. To get your keys as sorted integers, use

```
Object.keys(object1).map(Number).sort((a, b) => a-b)
```

Comment: true, but what if we want the creation order not sorted order? e.g keys [-1, 0, 3, 2, -3]

Comment: @anu You cannot. It's precisely why objects shouldn't be used for anything sensitive to order.

Comment: @anu Objects maintain creation order only for non-array-index keys, those always come first. Objects are still the wrong data structure when you want something ordered - store the order explicitly instead. Or use a `Map` at least.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense

Comment: Property keys are traversed in the following order:

First, the keys that are integer indices in ascending numeric order.
Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.

Comment: For more details about the traversing order you can read - https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html

Comment: @MonikaMangal Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

This is will, in case you don't want to change the type of the keys and keep them as strings.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1).sort()
```